# Java how to color a Rectangle

Tags: java, swing

I have a simple GUI application in Java. I just create a window with `JFrame` and put a rectangle in it.

My problem is that I can't color the area of the Rectangle.

I use the method `set.Color(Color.BLACK)`, but with this method it colors only the edge of the Rectangle.

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g2.drawRect(10,20,100,150);
  }
```

How can i color the area?

Comment: g2.fillRect(10,20,100,150)

Comment: Try fillRect(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect(int, int, int, int)

Comment: ok thank you very much.. But what is the different between drawrect and fillRect?

Comment: Go to my link below. It describes what fillRect() does. drawRect() draws the outline. You can probably guess what fillRect() does.

Answer (score 2):

To fill a rectange you use `Graphics#fillRect(int, int, int, int)`

Source: [java.awt.Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, use:

```
g2.fillRect(10,20,100,150)
```

instead of `drawRect`.